# Ошибка Worksheet object has no attribute range в Python и Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Необходимо работать с Excel таблицами в Python. Использую библиотеку openpyxl. Открываю один файл Excel и хочу выдернуть необходимые мне ячейки и вставить в новый файл (создал заранее check.xlsx).Если с одной ячейкой все нормально, то когда беру несколько ячеек, возникает ошибка: Worksheet object has no attribute range.

Гуглил до этого, писали, что старая версия Openpyxl, но это уже неактуально, так как поставил самую новую версию.

```
import openpyxl
#Чтение файла
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'C:\\Users\\Ринат\\Desktop\\Python\\ExcelPython\\Bogdan.xlsx')
#Выбор листа
sheet = wb['TDSheet']
#Считывание даннных
vals = [v[0].value for v in sheet.range['B11:B12']]
#Открытие второго файла для записи ответа
checkWb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'C:\\Users\\Ринат\\Desktop\\Python\\ExcelPython\\check.xlsx')
#Открытие листа ActRpa для записи ответа
sheetCheck = checkWb['ActRpa']
#записывам последовательность
i = 0
for rec in vals:
    sheetCheck.cell(row=i, column=2).value = rec
    i += 1
#Сохраняем данные
checkWb.save('C:\\Users\\Ринат\\Desktop\\Python\\ExcelPython\\check.xlsx')
```

Comment: Судя по коду в https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/8953233f5af287d9cdf3dae34e437e76bea5bd59/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py#lines-267 можно напрямую через квадратные скобки обращаться, т.е.:  `vals = [v[0].value for v in sheet['B11:B12']]`

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо, вы правы. Если кто будет искать такую же проблему, то возникла из-за того, что взял код с Habr, который на данный момент является не рабочим - https://habr.com/ru/post/232291/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[По текущему коду класса Worksheet](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/8953233f5af287d9cdf3dae34e437e76bea5bd59/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py#lines-267) можно напрямую через квадратные скобки обращаться, т.е.:

```
vals = [v[0].value for v in sheet['B11:B12']]
```

А способ через `.range(` уже устарел и был убран.